# Aurelia JS - iterate through children (kendo UI) elements?

Tags: javascript, aurelia

Consider the basic example given here:

- https://aurelia-ui-toolkits.github.io/demo-kendo/#/samples/slider-basic-use

... which is also available on gist.run:

- https://gist.run/?id=387c43948dc83acf59ea3497472bdfe9

In that `app.html`, there are several sliders constructed as `input` of `class="eqSlider"`, like this:

```
        <input repeat.for="value of equalizerSliderValues"
               ak-slider="k-orientation: vertical;
                                k-min.bind: -20;
                                k-max.bind: 20;
                                k-value.bind: value;
                                k-small-step.bind: 1;
                                k-large-step.bind: 20;
                                k-show-buttons.bind: false" class="eqSlider"/>
```

What I would want, is that I add an `attached()` method, and iterate through all these sliders of class `eqSlider`, print them out through `console.log()`, and call the `resize()` method ( http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/slider#methods-resize ) on each of them.

- Can I do this without `jquery` - if so, how?
- If not, how do I do that with `jquery` (as the `docs.telerik.com` example uses that)? I've tried adding:

  ```
  import * as $ from 'jquery';
  ```

... at top of `app.js` in the `gist.run` example, but it fails with:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (OK)
bluebird.min.js:29 Unhandled rejection Error: XHR error (404 OK) loading https://gist.host/run/1487343107475/jquery.js
    at o (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/systemjs/0.19.6/system.js:4:12694)
    at XMLHttpRequest.s.onreadystatechange (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/systemjs/0.19.6/system.js:4:13219)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As an alternative to what has been proposed by Jeff you could also use [this trick](https://gist.run/?id=67ed498e8103e86647466f85829a8d11).

Basically you can define an array of sliders where the initial `widget` property is null:

```
sliders = [{
  value: 10,
  widget: null
}, {
  value: 20,
  widget: null
}]
```

Then, iterating over this array using `repeat.for`, you can bind the `k-widget` to the `widget` property of each slider.

```
<input repeat.for="slider of sliders"
       ak-slider="k-value.bind: slider.value;
                  k-widget.bind: slider.widget"/>
```

After all sliders have been initialized, you end up with an array of sliders where the `widget` property is the Kendo control instance.

By using the `.map` function on this array you can get an array of all Kendo slider widgets: `var sliders = this.sliders.map(x => x.widget);`.

Since the k-widget value cannot be used after `attached()` has been executed, as explained [here](https://aurelia-ui-toolkits.gitbooks.io/kendoui-bridge-docs/content/what_you_need_to_know.html#595-how-to-get-to-the-kendo-control), you can use the TaskQueue to do what you would like to do from attached().

Comment: Thanks @JeroenVinke - I tried this too, but I cannot get it to work either - when I try to do `sliders = this.sliders.map(x => x.widget);` in the `attached()`, then I iterate through it with `for (var i=0; i<kendosliders.length; i++) { var slider = kendosliders[i]; console.log("ffl2", slider); ...}`, then `slider` is `null`, and thus `slider.resize()` will raise `TypeError: slider is null`. Can you provide a complete example (maybe in a `gist.run`) where the `resize()` actually works?

Comment: Many thanks @JeroenVinke - so what I was missing was in addition was `taskQueue`, good to know that...

Answer (score 2):

```
let sliders = document.querySelectorAll('.eqSlider');

for (let slider of Array.from(sliders)) {
    console.log(slider.outerHTML); // or whatever values you want.
    slider.resize();
}
```

Here's a gist showing how to do this by only searching through the element instead of the entire document:

https://gist.run/?id=debb0337a00d5ef063048fce62a691cf

Comment: Made a gist and changed innerHTML to outerHTML.

Comment: Sorry, I had to remove my accept @JeffG - in your gist.run (and in my code) when I uncomment `slider.resize()`, I don't get sliders anymore but textboxes, and I get JS error: `Unhandled rejection TypeError: slider.resize is not a function`,  so we're not getting to the actual element that has a `resize()` method according to the kendo-ui API. Any ideas how to get that working? Note that after kendoui is done, the actual widget is not just `input` anymore, but has also a bunch of `div`s etc...