# Aurelia JS - Kendo UI vertical sliders with height in percent?

Tags: javascript, css, kendo-ui, aurelia

I've taken a version of the code posted on [Aurelia JS - iterate through children (kendo UI) elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42301109/aurelia-js-iterate-through-children-kendo-ui-elements/42314012#42314012) and modified it slightly, here:

- https://gist.run/?id=323de53223d2ec872f17361378639556

I would basically like to express that the vertical sliders should be 90% of the height of the enclosing `div`; note that:

- If there is no CSS `height:` specification, the sliders get some height, and that is it
- If I set the CSS `height` (either via `div.eqSlider` in `basic-use.css`, or as an inline `style` attribute) in either `px` or `em`, then all is fine
- But, if I set the CSS `height` in percent `%` (either via `div.eqSlider` in `basic-use.css`, or as an inline `style` attribute), or to `calc(90%-10px)` or similar - then the display is completely messed up, as shown on the image below:

[image: gistrun.png]

So, is it somehow possible to set the height of these sliders to 90% of the height of the enclosing `div` - and if so, how?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think I fixed it - the problem was as is typical in these cases: by default, divs and such don't have a height defined, and their height gets computed based on their contents. Since the sliders in the example *are* the content, without any other further specification, their height in procent then either becomes recursive, or is percentage of height 0.

Which is why then one must ensure that the entire chain from `body` to the enclosing `div` have a height defined in % (in essence, 100%, except it may show scrollbar). And I thought I had done that in the previous example - but I made a mistake in the .css: I used a `.example` selector (for a class), whereas I should have used `#example` selector (for an id); and that broke the height calculation of the chain of nested divs.

I noticed that once I assigned borders to each and every div in the nested chain; and then could correct so they all have defined height. Once all of the divs - and thus the enclosing one - have a height, then the sliders can get a height in percent, either in the .css file, or by assignment from JavaScript (via `slider.wrapper.css("height", "50%");`)

And so, the corrected code is now on:

- https://gist.run/?id=fcfc066733ad903fa0575388a1637e4f

... and the output looks as expected:

[image: gistrun]