# Aurelia JS - run function on change of Kendo UI slider?

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, aurelia

Let's use the same example as in [Aurelia JS - Kendo UI vertical sliders with height in percent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42346425/aurelia-js-kendo-ui-vertical-sliders-with-height-in-percent):

- https://gist.run/?id=323de53223d2ec872f17361378639556

Now, let's say in `app.js`, I've added a function like this:

```
  sliderOnChange(e) {
    console.log("sliderOnChange",e);
  }
```

How can I call this function whenever each slider changes its value - and can I retrieve old value, new value, and which slider had that change?

I have tried modifying the slider code:

```
            <input repeat.for="slider of sliders"
                   ak-slider="
                   k-orientation: vertical;
                   k-min.bind: -20;
                                    k-max.bind: 20;
                                    k-value.bind: slider.value;
                                    k-widget.bind: slider.widget;
                                    k-small-step.bind: 1;
                                    k-large-step.bind: 20;
                                    k-show-buttons.bind: false" class="eqSlider"/>
```

... by adding attribute:

```
      kendo-change.trigger="sliderOnChange()"
```

... that does not work; also tried adding attribute:

```
      k-on-change.delegate: "sliderOnChange($event)"
```

... that does not work either; and I've tried adding to the `ak-slider` attribute:

```
                                    k-on-change.delegate: sliderOnChange;
```

... and you may have guessed it already, that does not work either...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `k-on-change.delegate="onChange($event.detail)"` as demonstrated [here](https://gist.run/?id=aba13a95bf1d931652c7dcde4da7eca0)